# Can additive inverses both be positive in a general algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra

Im looking for an algebraic structure with additive inverses for all of its elements... $\forall a\in X, \exists b\in X$ such that $a+b=e$, for additive identity $e$ and some abstract binary operation $+$.  There must be an ordering $\prec$ where $\forall x\in X$, if $x\ne e$ then $x\prec e$ or $e\prec x$, thus defining a notion of positivity and negativity.  Im curious to know if its possible in such a structure for both $a,b$ to be simultaneously $\prec e$ or for $e \prec$ both $a,b$ simultaneously.  It should be understood that Im looking for a non-trivial example of such a structure, thus making everything positive or everything negative is not accepted.

Comment: It probably depends on what other axioms you want $\prec$ to satisfy, since the trivial "everything is positive!" satisfies your question as written

Comment: If you don't place any more requirements on the order, then you can just take *any* group, and say that $a\prec b$ for all $a$ and $b$. However, in this case $\prec$ is not even a partial order.

Comment: @Joe, if $\prec$ isnt even a partial order then it doesnt really satisfy my question.

Comment: @Andrew, you make a valid point but I think my question implies, though not made explicit, that in fact not everything is positive. For the sake of argument go with that.  What more axioms are required? I think the idea here is to allow elements to exist on either side of the zero.

Comment: A good "ceiling" is a simply ordered commutative group: it satisfies all of your hypothesis (additive inverses, $\prec$ is a total ordering) plus the axiom $\forall a \forall b \forall c (a\prec b \rightarrow a+c\prec b+c)$, and in this structure it is definitely *not* the case that an element and its inverse can be both positive or both negative

Comment: If your partial order does not interact with the algebraic structure in any shape and form, in what sense does it define a notion of "positive"?

Comment: Here's a thought: $(Z, -, \leq)$. It's a quasigroup and I'm not too familiar with those so I don't know if that quite satisfies what you're looking for, but I don't have the time at this exact moment to work through the details

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$ with it's known addition and ordering that will bedenoted as $+,<$ respectively. We will define for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ the relation $\prec$ as follows:

- If $a\equiv b\mod 2$ then $a\prec b\iff a<b$
- If $a\neq b \mod 2$ then $a\prec b\iff a\equiv 0\mod 2$

Let's prove that $\prec$ is a strict total order  on $\mathbb{Z}$

- Irreflexive: Let $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a\equiv a\mod 2$, so $a\prec a\iff a<a$, but $a<a$ is always false, so also $a\prec a$ is false
- Transitive: Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\prec b$ and $b\prec c$, then if $a,b,c$ are all with the same parity then $a<b$ and $b<c$ so $a<c$. if $a$ is odd then because $a\prec b$ then $b$ must be odd as well, and by the same reasoning $c$ will be odd and we are done. if $c$ is even than it must be the case that $a,b$ are even as well. if $a$ is even and $c$ is odd then $a\prec c$ and we are done.
- Connected: Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\neq b$. if $a,b$ are of the same parity then because the relation $<$ is connected we know that $a<b$ or $b<a$, and that implies $a\prec b$ or $b\prec a$. if $a,b$ are of different parity than if $a$ is even so $a\prec b$, if $a$ is odd than $b\prec b$.

But notice that every odd integer $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ uphold $0\prec a$ and it's additive inverse is also an odd integer, so for all odd integers we can see that $0\prec -a,a$. On the contrary, every even integer upholds $0\prec a\iff 0<a$, so we will conclude that if $a$ is even then $0\prec a\iff -a\prec 0$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what properties you want the ordering to satisfy. Consider the case where $\prec$ is a *total order* defined on a group $G$. This means that $\prec$ satisfies the following three axioms:

1. Irreflixivity: There is no $a\in G$ such that $a\prec a$.
2. Transitivity: For all $a,b,c\in G$, if $a\prec b$ and $b\prec c$, then $a\prec c$.
3. Trichotomy: For all $a,b\in G$, we have $a\prec b$, or $b\prec a$, or $a=b$. (It now follows from the first two axioms that exactly one of these holds for all $a,b\in G$.)

The set $P$ of positive elements of $G$ is then defined as $\{x\in G:0\prec x\}$, where $0$ denotes the identity element of $G$.

In this set-up, it is very possible that there is an $x$ such that both $x$ and $-x$ belong to $P$. This is because none of the total order axioms have anything to do with the group operation $+$. For instance, let $G=\{-1,0,1,2\}$, and let $\prec$ be given by the usual ordering of the integers. Define $a+b$ as the sum of $a$ and $b$ in modulo $4$ arithmetic. Since $-2=2$, both $2$ and $-2$ are positive elements of $G$.

On the other hand, if we require that $P$ is closed under $+$, then it is impossible for there to be an $x$ such that both $x$ and $-x$ belong to $P$. Indeed, if $x$ and $-x$ were both positive, then $x+(-x)=0$ would be positive, contradicting the first axiom.